# Mongo aggregate $sum behavior

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, tornado-motor

I have this query in Motor (looks almost exactly as CLI query):

```
response = yield self.db.orders.aggregate([
        {'$match': {'reader.uid': reader.get('uid'), 'status': {'$in': statuses}}},
        {'$sort': {'create_datetime': -1}},
        {'$project': {'_id': 1, 'status': 1, 'create_datetime': 1, 'documents': 1}},
        {'$group': {
            '_id': 0,
            'info': {'$push': {'status': '$status', 'create_datetime': '$create_datetime', 'documents': '$documents'}},
            'total': {'$sum': 1}
        }},
        {'$skip': skip},
        {'$limit': int(limit)}
    ])
```

Need to get total count of documents before `$skip` and `$limit`. Not sure, how exactly `$sum` working, but in this query, I get the right result, but when I pass actual `_id`, the `total` value is 1:

```
        {'$group': {
            '_id': '$_id',
            'info': {'$push': {'status': '$status', 'create_datetime': '$create_datetime', 'documents': '$documents'}},
            'total': {'$sum': 1}
        }},
```

I want to get real `_id` and right `total` value in result.

Total newbie in Mongo, all answers are appreciated.

Comment: not sure why you get sum=0 when you group by _id, you sure there is no mistake? what is the type of your _id ?

Comment: Yes, I get 1, my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) groups/aggregate all documents together based on a certain `_id`.

When you are grouping documents by `_id=0`, all documents will be in the same group because all have the same `_id` that is `0`. 
[$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) will count all the documents in the same group by the specified value: `1`.

When you group by the original `_id` and the `_id` is unique across your collection you should get `sum=1` since there is only one document with that `_id` => one document in a group.

Comment: Does it mean, I can group by any identical field, say by `reader.uid`? In this way, I got the needed result, and original `_id` pushed to `info`.